# How would you share a theme between a Django app and a Wordpress blog?

Tags: django, wordpress, templates, themes

Trying to keep a consistent look & feel between a django site and a wordpress blog is turning into somewhat of a pain and I'm wondering if there's a way to set it up so that stuff only needs to be changed in one place.

Most of the appearance stuff that changes is in the header and footer which for Wordpress is in header.php and footer.php, and for Django it's in a base template.

I'd prefer to be able to have the Django template be the master thing that's edited, but either one would be preferable to having to keep both updated manually.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at [Deliverance](http://deliverance.openplans.org/); this is just the sort of thing it's intended for.

Answer (score 1):

This [recent post](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2009-November/028632.html) to the wp-hackers mailing list mentioned the [JSON API](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/) plugin that was written to do something similar to what you want to do, however with Rails.

In short, the WordPress installation becomes a data backend that is accessed by JSON from your Django-based frontend.  Comments are passed back through your frontend and saved in WordPress.